# How to resolve "There are no arguments to <name> depending on a template parameter"?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm converting my legacy VC++ project to be compatible with Android NDK and I'm getting a weird error. The message says:

```
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: procalc-core <= pcc_arithmetics.cpp
In file included from D:/Dokumenty/Dev/Android/ProCalc//jni/pcc_arithmetics.h:10:0,
                 from D:/Dokumenty/Dev/Android/ProCalc//jni/pcc_arithmetics.cpp:1:
D:/Dokumenty/Dev/Android/ProCalc//jni/pcc_common.h: In static member function 
'static std::string ProCalcCore::CommonTools::ToStringBase(T, int)':

D:/Dokumenty/Dev/Android/ProCalc//jni/pcc_common.h:102:68: error: there are no 
arguments to 'ConvertException' that depend on a template parameter, so a 
declaration of 'ConvertException' must be available [-fpermissive]

throw ConvertException(PROCALC_ERROR_SYNTAX_INVALID_INTEGER_BASE);
                                                                ^
D:/Dokumenty/Dev/Android/ProCalc//jni/pcc_common.h:102:68: note: (if you use 
'-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared 
name is deprecated)

make.exe: *** [D:/Dokumenty/Dev/Android/ProCalc//obj/local/armeabi/objs/procalc-
core/pcc_arithmetics.o] Error 1
```

The error is thrown in the following place:

```
template <typename T>
std::string CommonTools::ToStringBase(T val, int base)
{
    if (base < 2)
        throw ConvertException(PROCALC_ERROR_SYNTAX_INVALID_INTEGER_BASE);
```

The caps-named error value is a `#define`d int value.

`ConvertException` is declared in another file:

```
namespace ProCalcCore
{
    (...)
    class ConvertException : public InternalException
    {
    public:
        ConvertException(const unsigned long int & newErrorCode);
    };
```

When I try to change `ConvertException` to `ProCalcCore::ConvertException`, I get another error:

```
D:/Dokumenty/Dev/Android/ProCalc//jni/pcc_common.h:102:10: error: 'ConvertException' 
is not a member of 'ProCalcCore'
```

All dependencies are resolved correctly - in VS the project compiles without problems.

How can I solve it? What causes this error?

Comment: Add a forward declaration of your exception type or include a header with a declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In visual studio the project compiles without problems" is weak evidence that your dependencies are correct.

The problem is that `ConvertException` is not visible at the point where the `template` is declared.  Some versions of Visual Studio only try to bind such "free" types and expressions at the point where the `template` is instantiated, which is not correct under the C++ standard.

So your compiler is pointing out that it cannot work out what type `ConvertException` refers to.  In order for it to know what type it refers to, you need to either forward declare it (which can have its own problems), or `#include` the header file prior to using it.

If you think you are already `#include`ing it, often your problem is that the header file that contains `ConvertException` ends up `#include`ing `CommonTools::ToStringBase`.  The header file guards (or `#pragma once`) then eliminate the infinite loop.

Annoyingly, how the infinite loop is eliminated depends on which header file you include first!  If you include the `ConvertException` header file, it then includes `ToStringBase`, which includes `ConvertException` back.  That second `#include "ConvertException.h"` is eliminated by header-file `#define` guards.

If you instead included `ToStringBase` first, it would include `ConvertException`, which then includes `ToStringBase`, which is eliminated by the header guards.

So whatever header file is included first ends up being parsed *second*.

Comment: Damnit, I was sure, that the header file was included, but it turned out, that it weren't. Silly me. Thanks for the explanation - do you know a way to force VS compiler to be C++-standard compliant? (eg. compiler switch or project configuration etc.)

Comment: @Spook It is easy to make VS C++ standard compliant.  Configure your VS IDE to use a different compiler.